# Activator.GetObject for .netstandard

Tags: c#, .net-standard, activator

everybody!
I have a piece of code which calls win service remotely with  `Activator.GetObject(type, url)`. But the project is targeting .net framework and we're going to migrate to .net standard. The later, though, [does not provide such behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.getobject?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to).

Is there a way to do the same action in .net standard?

Comment: .NET remoting is the red-headed stepchild of the .NET Framework; while some of its aspects have been rebuilt/reintroduced in .NET Core (and hence back to .NET Standard) to support more basic infrastructure, the bits that do things with the internet are probably not coming back. Your best bet is to stick with Framework if you need this specific functionality. If this represents only a minor use case, you could refactor it to a separate assembly that's loaded conditionally, or dynamically invoke the method with reflection (after a platform check).

Comment: Remoting was never part of .NETCore, they resisted all temptation to add it back.  There was little temptation.  WCF was meant to replace it, which did get ported to .NETCore, eventually.  https://github.com/dotnet/wcf

Comment: The concept of a remoted object does not exist in .NET 6 and there are no plans to introduce it.