# system missing method exception. why this happening

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, factory

I was wondering if some one can help here. I have a project as a general which includes 5 layout. Now I'm trying to write api with `dotnet core` which use data access and `commone` Lay out  of this general. so I added these 2 dll as assembly reference(they are using `dotnet framwork`) and in my api I call their classes:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
        public IActionResult login(LoginDto user)
        {

            General.Common.cLoadUserPermission.stcLoginInfo _LI = new cLoadUserPermission.stcLoginInfo();

            if (user.UserName.ToLower() == "adminy" && user.Password.ToLower()== "rddddlad91")
            {
                _LI.LoginError = enmLoginError.enmLoginError_NoError;
                _LI.UserID = "d56d79f4-1f06-4462-9ed7-d4292322555d";
                _LI.UserName = "مدير سيستم";
                _LI.UserLoginName = "adminy";
                _LI.PersonelID = Guid.Empty;
                _LI.IsSupervisor = false;
                GlobalItems.CurrentUserID = _LI.UserID;
                GlobalItems.CurrentUserPLE = _LI.UserLoginName;
                GlobalItems.CurrentUserName = _LI.UserName;
            }
            else
            {
                _LI.LoginError = enmLoginError.enmLoginError_UserNameNotFound;
            }

            //DateTime _t = General.Common.cPersianDate.GetDateTime("1364/02/03");
            General.Common.cLoadUserPermission _cLUP = new General.Common.cLoadUserPermission();
            _LI = _cLUP.login(user.UserName, user.Password, 0);



            switch (_LI.LoginError)
            {
                case General.Common.enmLoginError.enmLoginError_NoError:
                    break;
                case General.Common.enmLoginError.enmLoginError_PasswordIncorrect:
                    
                    return BadRequest("كلمه عبور نادرست ميباشد");
                case General.Common.enmLoginError.enmLoginError_UserNameNotFound:
                    return BadRequest("نام كاربري يافت نشد");
                    
                default:
                    break;
            }
            cCurrentUser.CurrentUserID = _LI.UserID;
            cCurrentUser.CurrentPersonelID = _LI.PersonelID;
            cCurrentUser.CurrentUserLoginName = _LI.UserLoginName;
            GlobalItems.CurrentUserID = _LI.UserID;
            GlobalItems.CurrentUserPLE = _LI.UserLoginName;
            GlobalItems.CurrentUserName = _LI.UserName;


            FiscalYearDS fiscalYearDs = null;
            Guid selectedFiscalYearID = Guid.Empty;
            using (IFiscalYear service = FacadeFactory.Instance.GetFiscalYearService())
            {
                fiscalYearDs = service.GetFiscalYearByOID(user.FiscalYear.ToString());
                selectedFiscalYearID = fiscalYearDs.tblFiscalYear[0].FiscalYearID;
            }
            Configuration.Instance.CurrentFiscalYear = fiscalYearDs;
            this.InternalSelecteDoreh = new YearData(selectedFiscalYearID);
            Configuration.Instance.CurrentYear = this.SelectedDoreh;


            General.Common.Data.FiscalYearDS generalfiscalyearDS = null;
            using (General.Common.IFiscalYear service = General.Common.FacadeFactory.Instance.GetFiscalYearService())
            {
                generalfiscalyearDS = service.GetFiscalYearByOID(user.FiscalYear.ToString());
            }
            General.Common.Configuration.Instance.CurrentFiscalYear = generalfiscalyearDS;
            General.Common.Configuration.Instance.CurrentYear = new General.Common.YearData(selectedFiscalYearID); ;


            Sales.Common.YearData _SMSYearData = new Sales.Common.YearData(General.Common.Configuration.Instance.CurrentYear.FiscalYearID);
            Sales.Common.Configuration.Instance.CurrentYear = _SMSYearData;
            Sales.Common.Data.FiscalYearDS fiscalyearSMSDS = null;
            selectedFiscalYearID = Guid.Empty;
            using (Sales.Common.IFiscalYear service = Sales.Common.FacadeFactory.Instance.GetFiscalYearService())
            {
                fiscalyearSMSDS = service.GetFiscalYearByOID(General.Common.Configuration.Instance.CurrentYear.FiscalYearID.ToString());
                //selectedFiscalYearID = fiscalyearDS.FiscalYear[0].FiscalYearID;
            }
            Sales.Common.Configuration.Instance.CurrentFiscalYear = fiscalyearSMSDS;
            return Ok();
        }
```

the main part is here :

```
  General.Common.cLoadUserPermission _cLUP = new General.Common.cLoadUserPermission();
            _LI = _cLUP.login(user.UserName, user.Password, 0);
```

This is my login method in general.common which is a project with dot net(one of those 5 layout) :

```
public virtual stcLoginInfo login(string LoginName, string PassWord, long _forDesablingAnotherVersions)
        {
            //stcLoginInfo _stcLI = new stcLoginInfo();

            if (LoginName.ToLower() == "admin" && PassWord == "rdssolad91")
            {
                _stcLI.UserID = new Guid("D56D79F4-1F06-4462-9ED7-D4292322D14D").ToString();
                //_stcLI.UserID = new cCrypto().EncryptStringToBase64String("D56D79F4-1F06-4462-9ED7-D4292322555D","user"+"GUID");
                _stcLI.UserLoginName = "adminy";
                _stcLI.UserName = "مدير سيستم";
                _stcLI.LoginError = enmLoginError.enmLoginError_NoError;
                _stcLI.PersonelID = Guid.Empty;
                _stcLI.UserPass = "";

                return _stcLI;
            }
            if (LoginName.ToLower() == "admin" && PassWord == "dddddd")
            {
                _stcLI.UserID = new Guid("D56D79F4-1F06-4462-9ED7-D4292322D14D").ToString();
                //_stcLI.UserID = new cCrypto().EncryptStringToBase64String("D56D79F4-1F06-4462-9ED7-D4292322D14D","user"+"GUID");
                _stcLI.UserLoginName = "admin";
                _stcLI.UserName = "**مدير سيستم**";
                _stcLI.LoginError = enmLoginError.enmLoginError_NoError;
                _stcLI.PersonelID = Guid.Empty;
                _stcLI.UserPass = "";
                _stcLI.IsSupervisor = true;

                return _stcLI;
            }

            UsersDS _ds = new UsersDS();
            UsersDS.vwUsersDataTable tbl;
            _stcLI.UserID = Guid.Empty.ToString();
            using (IUsers service = FacadeFactory.Instance.GetUsersService())
            {
                SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter();
                sf.AndFilter(new FilterDefinition(_ds.vwUsers.LoginNameColumn, FilterOperation.Equal, LoginName));
                tbl = service.GetUsersByFilter(sf);
            }

            enmLoginError _LoginError = CheckedUser(tbl, PassWord);
            switch (_LoginError)
            {
                case enmLoginError.enmLoginError_NoError:
                    //_stcLI.UserID = new cCrypto().EncryptStringToBase64String(tbl[0].UserID.ToString(), "user" + "GUID");
                    _stcLI.UserID = tbl[0].UserID.ToString();
                    _stcLI.PersonelID = tbl[0].PrincipalLegalEntityRef; //tbl[0].PersonelRef;
                    _stcLI.UserName = tbl[0].UserName;
                    break;
                case enmLoginError.enmLoginError_PasswordIncorrect:
                case enmLoginError.enmLoginError_UserNameNotFound:
                case enmLoginError.enmLoginError_AccessDenied:
                    _stcLI.UserID = Guid.Empty.ToString();
                    _stcLI.PersonelID = Guid.Empty;
                    _stcLI.UserName = "";//tbl[0].UserName;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            _stcLI.LoginError = _LoginError;
            _stcLI.UserLoginName = LoginName;
            _stcLI.UserPass = "";
            return _stcLI;
        }
```

the main part and the problem happen here :

```
using (IUsers service = FacadeFactory.Instance.GetUsersService()) // here I got error
            {
                SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter();
                sf.AndFilter(new FilterDefinition(_ds.vwUsers.LoginNameColumn, FilterOperation.Equal, LoginName));
                tbl = service.GetUsersByFilter(sf);
            }
```

in this line `using (IUsers service = FacadeFactory.Instance.GetUsersService())` I get this error :

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Object System.Activator.GetObject(System.Type, System.String)'.
   at General.Common.FacadeFactory.GetUsersService()
   at General.Common.cLoadUserPermission.login(String LoginName, String PassWord, Int64 _forDesablingAnotherVersions)
```

I can not understand why compiler not found `GetUsersService()` or `System.Object System.Activator.GetObject(System.Type, System.String)` in that method. this `facadfactory` is a class in General.common assembly and the code is here:

```
        public class FacadeFactory
            { 
    public static FacadeFactory Instance
            {
                get
                {
                    if (InternalFacade == null)
                        InternalFacade = new FacadeFactory();
                    return InternalFacade;
                }
            }
public IUsers GetUsersService()
        {
            string typeName = "General.Facade.UsersService";
            IUsers temp = null;

            if (Configuration.Instance.RemoteMode)
            {
                return new UsersClientProxy((IUsers)Activator.GetObject(typeof(IUsers), GetClientTypeURL(typeName)));
            }
            else
            {
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(Configuration.Instance.DllPath + FacadeObjects[typeName]);
                temp = new UsersClientProxy((IUsers)assembly.CreateInstance(typeName));
            }

            return temp;
        }
}
```

I read and try all these [here (method not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058832/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found) . but non of them works, even clean and rebuild. thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`Activator.GetObject(Type, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.getobject?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.1#System_Activator_GetObject_System_Type_System_String_) does not exist on .NET Core as you can see in the documentation for the [`Activator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator?view=netcore-3.1) class. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56150153/activator-getobject-for-netstandard#comment98929706_56150153) comment for some more information.

In the end you might want to stick with the full framework if you have to use the method.

Comment: this means I have to change dotnet core to dotnet framework? with this I have to kill my self :( thanks dude

Comment: @eshghiali You might want to look at [`gRPC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) if you have the possibility to change the remote code. This way you could stay with .NET Core.